# map/import data from spreadsheet in django models for a particular field

Tags: python, django

I have a django model in which i have my data-

```
class School():
    school = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    roll_no = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    parking_no = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The `parking_no` does not have any data, I have an excel (spreadsheet) document(.xlsx) from which i want to map my django models and wants to import the entry of `parking_no` only. `(models already have other data)`

The excel document have the data like follow-

```
SCHOOL ROLLNO PARKING_NO 
sch1    u101    p101
sch2    u102    p102
```

The `roll_no` is unique in my django models and excel document, based on the `roll_no`, How can I map / import to fill the `parking_no` alone in my models.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your XML document updating each model.

```
 for row in rows:
       School.objects.filter(roll_no=row['ROLLNO']).update(parking_no=row['PARKING_NO'])
```